# Facebook publish on timeline

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

Is it possible to publish any text to user timeline without dialog? I know how to do that with feed dialog, but I need only post some text.

Comment: You can use Graph API to post without feed dialog

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like

```
FB.api(
     FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body, message: 'My message is ...' }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert(response);
       } else {
            alert(response));
```

}
 });
 }